# Sequential compactness implies totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

I am attempting to prove sequential compactness implies totally bounded by using collections of open covers. I feel like I am missing something, especially with how I defined $\epsilon$. Is the proof correct?

We will prove by contradiction. First define a collection of open balls with  radius $\epsilon > 0$ centered at each $x_i \in X$ as $C_\epsilon = \{B_\epsilon (x_i)\}_{x_i \in X}$, ($C_\epsilon$ can be an infinite set). We show that $C_\epsilon$ is in fact an open covering for a given $\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be an arbitrary real number. Since every element $x_i$ is contained in the open ball $B_\epsilon (x_i)$ centered at its self, the union $\cup_{x_i \in X} B_\epsilon (x_i)$  will contain every element of $X$, therefore $C_\epsilon$ is an open cover of $X$. Since $X$ is sequentially compact, it is also compact. Hence, by definition of compactness, there exists a finite subcover $C_\epsilon^\prime$ that still covers $X$. Assume that $X$ is not totally bounded. Then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$, such that any finite collection of open balls each centered at $x_i \in X$ does not cover $X$. This implies that for some $x_0 \in X$, we have that $x_0 \notin \cup_{x_i \in X} B_\epsilon(x_i)$. It is left to define $\epsilon$.

Define the fixed radius as $\epsilon = \inf \{d(x_i, x_0) : x \in X, \forall x_i \neq x_0\}$, that is, the closest distance from $x_0$ to the center of the nearest ball $B_\epsilon^\star (x_i)$; knowing that $x \notin B_\epsilon^\star (x_i)$, then for each $x_i$, $d(x_i, x_0) \geq \epsilon$. Since $x_0$ is not contained in the nearest ball, it must not be contained in \textit{any} finite collection of open balls. The union of these balls does not contain $x_0$, thus the collection does not cover $X$. However, we previously showed that we can find a finite cover of open balls of $X$ with any arbitrary $\epsilon$, but we defined an $\epsilon$ such that it produces a finite collection of balls that does not cover $X$, which produces a contraction. Therefore, $X$ must be totally bounded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [totally bounded metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108762/totally-bounded-metric-spaces)

Comment: The difference in my question is if using the theorem that seq implies compactness does not invalidate my proof, given that totally bounded is part of the proof for that theorem. It seems that using that theorem makes proving totally bounded a bit circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is finished at the end of your first paragraph: starting with the assumption that $X$ is compact, you took an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and showed that there exists a finite collection of radius-$\epsilon$ open balls whose union is $X$.

There is no need to make this a proof by contradiction and therefore no need to define a specific $\epsilon$.